# How do I convert a column of large objects to long text?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot with Hibernate, JPA and PostgreSQL. I'm wanting to convert database large objects into text content. Previously I was defining my long text in my JPA entity as `@Lob`:

```
@Lob
String description;
```

I then discovered that often problems are created using `@Lob`'s and decided to rather change them to:

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")
String description;
```

Which is represented in the database as a text type. Unfortunately, now the reference numbers (oid's) of the previous large objects are stored in my rows instead of the actual content. For example:

```
id | description
---------------------
 1 | 463784           <- This is a reference to the object rather than the content
```

instead of:

```
id | description
---------------------
 1 | Once upon a time, in a galaxy...
```

My question is now that we have thousands of rows of data in the database, how do I write a function or perform a query to replace the large object id with the actual text content stored in the large object?

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90942

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special thanks to @BohuslavBurghardt for pointing me to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90942) answer. For your convenience:

`UPDATE table_name SET column_name = lo_get(cast(column_name as bigint))`

Comment: I had the same problem with Spring, Postgres and JPA (Hibernate).

Answer (score 3):

I needed some additional conversion:

`UPDATE table_name SET text_no_lob = convert_from(lo_get(text::oid), 'UTF8');`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Spring, Postgres and JPA (Hibernate). I had a payload field that was like below

```
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "PAYLOAD")
private String payload;
```

I wanted to change the data type to **text** to support large data. So I used @Lob and I got the same error. To resolve that I first changed my field in my Entity like below:

```
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "PAYLOAD")
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
private String payload;
```

And because my data in this column was some scalar(Number) I have changed it to normal text with below command in Postgres:

```
 UPDATE MYTABLE SET PAYLOAD = lo_get(cast(PAYLOAD as bigint))
```

Thanks a lot @Sipder.